# Create Unordered List with bullet as ornament while hovering

Tags: html, css

I would like to create an unordered list that could display a bullet under each link like this image attached

[image: Image1]

Could someone recommend me something to achieve this?

Comment: Why under first only?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? We won't write code for you and we won't recommend software or libraries, that's off-topic here

Comment: @NenadVracar As in hovering over a link/unordered list element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove default bullets from `ul` with `list-style: none` and then create custom bullets with `:after` pseudo element.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  font-weight: bold;
}
li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
li:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #682E73;
}
li:hover {
  color: #682E73;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LOREM</li>
  <li>LOREM</li>
  <li>LOREM</li>
  <li>LOREM</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @NenadVracar that helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone wants to know how to keep the actual page active with the bullet at his 100% of opacity, here's the extra code

the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
    <li>link4</li>
</ul>
```

And in the CSS

```
li.active:after {
content: '';
width: 7px;
height: 7px;
position: absolute;
bottom: -15px;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
background: #682E73;
color: #682E73;
border-radius: 50%;
opacity: 1;
}
```